# ¿Como finalizar la comunicación con el servidor usando node.js?

Tags: nodejs

lo que quiero lograr es: al de **click** en el link de contáctenos haga lo que tenga que hacer y si por x o y motivo hay algun error, el navegador termine la conexion permaneciendo en la ruta original (`index`) sin necesidad de recargar la pagina.

tengo los codigo son los siguientes

jade:

```
extends layout

block content
   a(href="/contacto") contáctenos
```

js:

```
router.get('/contacto', function(req, res, next) {
            // hacer algo..
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de lo que necesitas pero prueba esto a ver si es lo que quieres hacer :S

```
router.get('/contacto', function(req, res, next) {
        res.redirect('back');
     });
```

Comment: ya lo probé, es casi lo que necesito, realmente seria eso pero sin que se recargara la pagina, la respuesta soluciona parte de mi problema

Comment: Si necesitas que no se recargue la página o usas AJAX o WebSockets. No hay más.